# Open very large Excel file

Tags: stata

I have been sent data in Excel format, which I want to import into Stata.

The file is very large and I get the following error:

> "*The file you are attempting to open is too large.
>
>   The maximum size allowed for *.xlsx files in 40 mb*"

Obviously this wouldn't be my preferred format, but can I get around the problem by only inputing specified columns?

Answer (score 3):

As the help file of the command `import excel` clearly states:

> *"...For performance, import excel imposes a size limit of 40 MB for Excel 2007/2010 (.xlsx) files..."*

You can get around this limitation by saving the file as `csv` (e.g. myfilename) from within Excel.

Then you can use Stata's `import delimited` command to do the job:

```
import delimited myfilename.csv, clear
```

Note that you can also do the conversion from `xlsx` to `csv` in Python or R if you do not have Microsoft Excel installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to import large Excel files I use the following:

```
set excelxlsxlargefile on
```

I know my computer may get slow while loading, but I would rather not go through the inconvenience of converting the `.xlsx` into `.csv` files.

Hope you find this useful sometime.

Comment: This is an undocumented feature, which sadly doesn't always work from my experience. Stata often crashes in the process. The `csv` approach on the other hand works every time and I suspect this is why `excelxlsxlargefile` remains undocumented.

Comment: Good to know, although it never happened to me (I have not used it many times). Does it crash quickly, or may it try to import for (say) 10 minutes and then crash? If it crashes quickly, it might be worth trying first; nothing to lose I guess.

Comment: It causes Stata to crash at random intervals and it depends every time on how large the file is. This probably happens because the memory overhead to go through the `xml` file is huge. The point is that it is an unreliable feature which should not normally be used.